# Longitude, Latitude to XY coordinate conversion

Tags: iphone, latitude-longitude, coordinate-systems

I want to now how to convert longitude, latitude to its equivalent xy coordinate components in iPhone programming. (I am using only CoreLocation programming, and want to show a point on iPhone screen without any map).

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well the exact conversion depends on exactly which part of the Earth you want to show, and the stretching along longitude varies according to latitude, at least in [Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

That being said, even if you don't want to display an actual MapKit map, it would probably be easiest to create an [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) and keep it to one side. If you set the area you want to display appropriately on that (by setting the `region` property), you can use `convertCoordinate:toPointToView:` to map from longitude and latitude to a 2d screen location.

Note that MKMapView adjusts the region you set so as to make sense for the viewport its been given (eg, if you gave it a region that was a short fat rectangle, but the view it had was a tall thin rectangle, it'd pick the smallest region that covers the entire short fat rectangle but is the shape of a tall thin rectangle), so don't get confused if you specify a region with the top left being a particular geolocation, but then that geolocation isn't at the exact top left of the view.

Comment: i am not using any map, i want to simply convert a longitude, latitude point in corresponding xy points (and translating them to pixels) to show it on a UIImageview in iphone.

Comment: I don't think I was completely clear in my answer — the easiest way is to create an MKMapView, give it the region your image covers, then use convertCoordinate:toPointToView: without ever actually showing the MKMapView. Then display something at the point it returns any way you want.