# convert latitude and longitude into x and y cordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Longitude, Latitude to XY coordinate conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186029/longitude-latitude-to-xy-coordinate-conversion)

In my iphone application i am getting latitude and longitude of my current place.But I want to draw a line graph taking these latitude and longitude as points.How this is possible??

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186029/longitude-latitude-to-xy-coordinate-conversion   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609379/how-do-i-convert-coordinates-to-a-latitude-longitude

Comment: Thankyou for the link..But now also I am not clear about drawing line graph..:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeInFloat, longitudeInFloat);
MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coord);
NSLog(@"x is %i and y is %i",point.x,point.y);
```

Comment: What to import to include MKMapPoint??

Comment: You have to import <MapKit/MapKit.h> .